# How can i clear flutter firestore cache

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I turned a value in databese into a map from the list, but it still sees the old one
So how can i clear firestore cache ?

```
Firestore.instance.settings(persistenceEnabled: false);
```

I use this code but give me error

> Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, FirebaseFirestore has already been started and its settings can no longer be changed. You can only call setFirestoreSettings() before calling any other methods on a FirebaseFirestore object., null)

Comment: Clearing persistence is not meant for the normal operation of your app.  It's intended to be used during testing.  It's recommended that if you don't want the default cahing behavior, you should disable caching altogether.  Please read the statement in the API docs for Android: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FirebaseFirestore.html#clearPersistence()

Answer (score 1):

The error message is not about clearing the cache, but about where in your code you change Firestore settings. Specifically, you can only change settings in the first call to `Firestore.instance` and in your case there is another call happening before you call `Firestore.instance.settings(persistenceEnabled: false)`.

The solution is to find the other call, and make sure `Firestore.instance.settings(persistenceEnabled: false)` is the first call to Firestore that your app makes.

Comment: It gives the same error wherever I put it. Is there another way?

Comment: That means there's still another Firestore call happening before you try to change the settings. If you edit your question to include an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), we can probably better help you troubleshoot where that is coming from.

Answer (score -1):

You can go with this nicely:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.settings =
    Settings(persistenceEnabled: false);
```